# Saving an Array to PropertiesService in Google Apps Script

Tags: array, google-apps-script

I have the same array set up as a variable inside of each function - I want to make this easier to manage. The array contains multiple strings of values. I’ve attached code below that I've been working on.

I would like to save this array to PropertiesService making it persistent across all executions. I already tried moving the variable out of the functions to make it global, but since I am iterating through the array, this didn't seem to work. I believe each call resets a global array. PropertiesService is hard to figure out because it only accepts one value, hoping someone can help with a string!

```
Var artistIdsArray = [“29457”, “28194”, “91424”, “53523”, “64824”];


PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('artistNumber', JSON.stringify(artistIdsArray) );


var  artistId1 = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty(artistNumber));
```

The code I have seems to be working. There are no errors. Just wanted a second set of eyes before I add it across the script.